# SQL query to sum a column prior to date and show all entries after that date

Tags: sql

I have a table where limits were sanctioned to the customer

[image: Customer Table]

I am trying to get the output as below picture i.e. total amount sanctioned till particular date

[image: Required Output]

I am trying below code but this sums the total sanction amount

```
select gam.id, sum(SANCTION_AMOUNT) from gam 
join (select ID,ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE from gam where ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE between'01-04-2019' and '30-04-2019' AND SCHEME_CODE IN  ('SB','CCKLY')) ) action
 on( gam.ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE <=action.ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE and gam.id=action.cust_id) group by gam.id;
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Please only tag the relevant RDBMS

Comment: @erdeepak . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, this can be a way:

```
select id, sanction_amount, scheme_code, account_open_date,
       sum(sanction_amount) over (partition BY ID order by account_open_date) as total_sanction_amount
from gam
order by account_open_date
```

Comment: . . This is standard SQL and works in the more recent versions of MySQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your database is MySQL or Oracle, But this below script is workable in most of the database. Just adjust the table and column names accordingly.

You can check MySQL [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cfd619db9545f73c6982cd35a913b23a)

```
SELECT *,
(
    SELECT SUM(sanction_Amount) 
    FROM Your_Table B
    WHERE B.ID = A.ID 
    AND B.acc_open_date <= A.acc_open_date
) Total_sanction_Amount
FROM Your_Table A
```